# Exponentiation of singular cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

A cardinal $\kappa$ is regular if and only if $\kappa=cf(\kappa)$. So if $\kappa$ is regular, $\lambda<\kappa$ and $f:\lambda\to\kappa$, then $f$ is bounded in $\kappa$, i.e. there is $\mu<\kappa$ such that $f\in\mu^\lambda$.

This leads to the observation that $$\kappa^\lambda=\bigcup_{\mu<\kappa}\mu^\lambda.$$

I would like to find a counterexample to this equality in the case $\kappa$ is a singular cardinal.

My attempt consists of considering $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$, $\lambda=cf(k)=\aleph_0$ and using the fact that $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$, to conclude computing $\bigcup_{\mu<\kappa}\mu^\lambda=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\aleph_n^{\aleph_0}$, which I would like to be $\aleph_\omega$. Does this work? If yes, how one can prove this last fact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is consistent with ZFC that $2^{\omega}\ge \aleph_{\omega+1}\land \forall m\,(\omega<m<2^{\omega} \implies 2^m=2^{\omega}).$ Reference topic: Martin's Axiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=\beth (\omega)=\cup_{n\in \omega}\beth (n)$ where $\beth(0)=\omega$ and $\beth(n+1)=2^{\beth (n)}.$ Let $l=\omega.$

If $m<k$ then for some $n\in \omega$ we have $m\le \beth(n)$ so $$m^l\le  (\beth(n))^l\le (2^{\beth (n)})^l=2^{\beth(n)\cdot l}=2^{\beth(n)\cdot \omega}= 2^{\beth (n)}=\beth (n+1)\le k.$$ So we have $$\bigcup_{m<k}\,m^l\le \left|\bigcup_{m<k}(\{m\}\times k)\right|=k\cdot k=k.$$

By Konig's Theorem (a.k.a. Konig's Lemma ) we have $$k<k^{cf(k)}=k^{\omega}=k^l.$$

Comment: The $k$ in my Answer is a strong limit cardinal so we actually have $k^{cf(k)}=2^k.$

Comment: The notation is usually $\beth_\omega$, rather than $\beth(\omega)$. Although I vaguely recall seeing both in use.

Answer (score 0):

That's the right idea, but it's not that simple: keep in mind that we could have e.g. $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega^2+17}$, so $(\aleph_\omega)^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$ does *not* obviously tell us that $(\aleph_\omega)^{\aleph_0}>(\aleph_n)^{\aleph_0}$ for all $n<\omega$.

Of course, if we assume GCH then we get $(\aleph_n)^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_n$ for all $n<\omega$. This suggests that we replace the $\aleph$-hierarchy, which may or may not play well in this context, with something else - and then look at the $\omega$th term of *that* hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Consistency of results such as the one you said are exactly what get me in trouble while trying to prove it! It seems to me that your answer suggests that it is somehow necessary to do assumptions other than ZFC in order to get provability of the non-equality κ^λ\not=U_{μ<κ}μ^λ) for some (singular) κ and λ, isn't it?

Comment: @NicolaCarissimi No, you don't need anything besides ZFC - you just have to choose the counterexamples more carefully.